# "Cannot GET /api/users/2" why is my GET request not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

`"Cannot GET /api/users/2"` why is my GET request not working for a user with an id of 2?

The query `http://localhost:3000/api/users` works but i'm trying to find an individual user based on their id and this is not working in my code below.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const users = [
    [{name: 'liam', id: 1}, {name: 'jon', id: 2}]
];

app.get('/api/users', (req, res ) => {
    res.send(users);
})


app.get('/api/users:id', (req, res ) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    const user = users.filter(u => u.id === id) [0]
    res.send(user)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000.......'));
```

---

When I do "`http://localhost:3000/api/users/1`" nothing displays in my browser.

I have updated the code to `app.get('/api/users/:id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a slash:

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', …)
```

Also, you have an array-in-an-array, which is probably not what you intended. Use this:

```
const users = [
  {name: 'liam', id: 1}, {name: 'jon', id: 2}
];
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I'm new to this, what a silly mistake :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @Liam see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this
app.get('/api/users/:id',..)